# Getting previous and next mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table, in this table I have 20 columns, My default value starts from 2-11 displaying  only 10 results. When the user clicks the previous button, I want to display the previous 1-10 result. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "Pagination" is what you call that: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%5Bmysql%5D+pagination

Comment: Beyond this, we can't really help you without seeing your code or table structure.

Answer (score 2):

You have to send page as parameter to get paginating.
Rest is easy. In SQL you have LIMIT clause which gets data limited to limit and offset variables you set. Example:

You have a table with 100 rows. If you want to get first 10 you have to write something like:

```
SELECT columns FROM table ... LIMIT 0,10
```

if you want to get next 10 rows the query should be

```
SELECT columns FROM table ... LIMIT 10,10
```

And so on

page Parameter shows what page you are displaing and offset is easy to calculate from it.

```
$offset = $currentPage*$limit;
```